# I have created an MWAA Cluster using terraform. I am trying to import variables using curl command. But it fails with an 403 Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, airflow, mwaa

I have created an MWAA Cluster using terraform. I am trying to import variables using the curl command. But it fails with a 403 Exception.
Airflow Version: v1.10.12
Exception:

You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Script used:

```
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOF
    export MWAA_ENVIRONMENT=${var.mwaa_name}
    OP=$(aws mwaa create-cli-token --name $MWAA_ENVIRONMENT)
    CLI_TOKEN=$(echo $OP | jq -r '.CliToken')
      curl -s --request POST "https://test/aws_mwaa/cli" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer $CLI_TOKEN" \
     --header "Content-Type: text/plain" \
     --data-raw "variables -s $key $value"
EOF
```

Comment: Is this a part of the Terraform code or this is unrelated to to it? If it is related to Terraform, please add it to the question.

Comment: Yes, it is related to terraform and I am trying to use local-exec there.

Comment: Can you add the terraform code to the question then?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use MWAA CLI you need to make sure you are following these [prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/call-mwaa-apis-cli.html#call-mwaa-apis-cli-prereqs:%7E:text=AWS%20account%20access%20in%20AWS%20Identity%20and%20Access%20Management%20(IAM)%20to%20the%20Amazon%20MWAA%20permissions%20policy%20Full%20API%20and%20console%20access%20policy%3A%20AmazonMWAAFullApiAccess.)

- AWS account access in AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) to the Amazon MWAA permissions policy in Apache Airflow UI access policy: AmazonMWAAWebServerAccess.
- AWS account access in AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) to the Amazon MWAA permissions policy Full API and console access policy: AmazonMWAAFullApiAccess.

Answer (score 0):

This python script is allowing me to upload a sinlge variable to mwaa instance but If I pass nested json as a input text it's giving me 500 error.

```html
val = (key + " " + str(json_dictionary[key]))
        mwaa_auth_token = 'Bearer ' + mwaa_cli_token['CliToken']
        mwaa_webserver_hostname = 'https://{0}/aws_mwaa/cli'.format(mwaa_cli_token['WebServerHostname'])
        raw_data = f"variables set export -v js.json"
        mwaa_response = requests.post(
            mwaa_webserver_hostname,
            headers={
                'Authorization': mwaa_auth_token,
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                },
            data=raw_data
            )
```

Full script is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-variables-import.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).